# VHDL: динамический срез массива

Tags: массивы, железо, vhdl

Есть достаточно большой массив STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 639).
По входящему сигналу, необходимо брать следующие два элемента массива.  Для этого я делаю примерно следующее:

```
counter := counter+1;
MyVar := Data((counter*2) to ((counter*2)+1));
```

но наталкиваюсь на ошибку:

```
Error (10394): VHDL error at module.vhd(227): left bound of range must be a constant
```

Есть идеи как заставить это работать?

Обновление 0.2:

На некотором форуме поступило предложение использовать побитовое присваивание  каждого элемента массива каждому соответствующему элементу переменной.

```
MyVar(0) := Data(counter * 2);
MyVar(1) := Data(counter * 2 + 1);
```

При использовании 2битной переменной это работает, но что если нужно будет сделать 8-ми, или 16-ти битный срез? Проблему обошли, но не исправили, вопрос всё ещё открыт.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант пришедший в голову: если длина используемого массива всегда разная, то придется создать переменную такого же размера и затем просто обращаться с конкретным элементам в дальнейшем:

```
signal buff : std_logic_vector(0 to 639);
...
myvar <= buff(16 to 22);
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyVar(0 to 1)  := Data((counter*2) to ((counter*2)+1)) ;`